# Center Player Element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have WP site here: http://www.agapegreekradio.com/

And I run to some issues. I want the text and the player to be centered:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
 <div class="listen_section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 video_block">
            <h2>listen <span>live</span></h2>
            <!--<img src="<?php //echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() )?>/images/img3.png" alt=""/>-->
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('online-radio'); ?>
          </div>
          <?php include_once('homesider.php'); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know how to center it. How can i do it?

Please help you can use Google Chrome's Inspect Element to check this.

Thanks!

Comment: Tried putting a center tag around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use following classes on this tag:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 video_block">
    // content goes here...
</div>
```

and remove `margin: 0 auto` from inline styles...

Answer (score 0):

add class text-center along with row, replace col-lg-3 and col-md-3 with col-lg-12 and col-md-12 respectively.

and add this in your style sheet:

> div#serverroom.net{ margin:0 auto !important; }

hope this will work.

Comment: I tried this however I have an issue with centering the text h1 see screenshot: http://prnt.sc/asfy7g

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just add col-md-3 div before video-block div and make your video block div as col-md-6 and give text align center to it.

Comment: I tried this however I have an issue with centering the text h1 see screenshot: http://prnt.sc/asfy7g

Comment: did you make video block as col-md-6? because if you give text align center to it then the text should be in center according to its width.